# SCDF Jobs not coming up properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have some jobs on SCDF. When I start these jobs they start and end at the same time on SCDF but when I see logs, the job is in still running state. Due to this several jobs are getting triggered at the same time and.This results in infinite running of the composed job which have many sub jobs in it. Here you can see the start and end time is same [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXBVU.png)

**This started when i updated my spring boot version to 2.7.1  from 2.1.1.Release and i have also updated several dependencies such as**

1. Starter batch version to 2.6.9
2. Spring batch core version to 4.3.3
3. Spring cloud task dependencies to 2.4.3
4. Spring cloud dependency to 2021.0.3
5. Spring cloud starter bootstrap to 3.1.3

So the thing is the jobs are running fine on kube{*Rancher Desktop*}But on dataflow dashboard its not coming properly with the same time of starting and ending.